# Constructing a function which fails the Mean Value Theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

I want to find an example of a function $f$ which is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$ but does not satisfy the Mean Value Theorem. I need to explicitly show that $f$ does not satisfy the theorem.

Would the $\int_a^b f(x)\,d dx = F(b) - F(a)$ be a possible function?

Comment: In the future, it is very helpful if you can format your questions using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also, it is invaluable to include your own thoughts, attempts, background, etc. in your questions to help potential answerers. For more information, see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Answer (score 0):

Take $f(x)=1_{x\geq\frac{1}{2}}$. $f$ is monotone, so riemann integrable.

Comment: How does that function not satisfy the Mean Value Theorem?